# jQuery UI button: How do I override the classes used for a single button?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am using the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library out of the box, based on a theme.

Having links rendered as buttons is great, however I need to override some buttons with different colours.

How do I specify an specific class for a particular button to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, give the particular button or buttons an id, and:

```
$("#buttonId").removeClass().addClass("myClass");
```

If you want to apply it to multiple buttons each with its own id:

```
$("#buttonId, #anotherButton").removeClass().addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: While this will usually work, I prefer to use CSS for look and feel and javascript for behavior as much as possible.  It should be possible to simply restyle aspects of individual elements with CSS alone.  Using javascript to do it unnecessarily couples the look of the page to the use of javascript, IMO.

Comment: I tries this by override the ui-button-text class by doing:
$("#SaveButton").removeClass("ui-button-text").addClass("ui-button-text-save");
but this does'nt work. 
Having nothing in removeClass() removes more css than required I think?

Comment: Its seems that one has to change a few classes? not sure how to override a bunch of classes without a lot more styles or code?

Comment: Marking this one as the answer since I needed to add some code: Just added a class to the button to override some styles, no need to remove any classes.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend looking at the CSS for the jQuery UI buttons and duplicating the structure of the CSS which specifies the buttons, but with your own class instead of the jQuery UI classes.  Make the overrides that you need in this CSS and include it after the jQuery UI CSS. CSS uses a combination of the most specific selector **and** ordering to determine which values to apply.  By doing this you will make sure that you have the same specificity for each of the CSS selectors used by jQuery so that your CSS takes precedence based on order.

Smashing Magazine has an [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that probably has more information than you care to know about the specificity issue.

Comment: @tvanfosson: This works and is great, now what I didnt include in my question, which I should have, is that this needs to be switchable. Eg: highlighting a next or save buttons depending on some other actions. I guess some code (jquery) is required.

Comment: @Mark - if the changes aren't merely due to hovering over the button, which you can handle with CSS then, yes, take a look at @Karim's answer and use remove/addClass in your jQuery to update the class associated with the element based on the user's behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can also:

1. Use Developer Tools in the browser (Chrome has great ones).
2. See what class from jQuery UI defines the button color.
3. Override it in your CSS file with the "!important" attribute.

For example, when I needed to override jQuery UI spinner control and remove the borders, I found the class that defines the borders using Chrome Dev Tools. Then in CSS: I added something like that:

`.<jquery-ui-class-that-i-found> { border: 0px !important; }`

Works great!

Answer (score 2):

I think the button API should include a configuration like this where you can change color etc. by passing parameters

```
$("button").button({background:"FFFFFF",hover:"FFFFF"});
```

this is just an idea where you can change some of its visual attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked for me:
$(".btnSave").removeClass("ui-state-default").addClass("SaveButtonStyling");

Basically needed to remove the ui-state-default class and then add my own for the background colour etc.

Thsi meant that the rounded corner class etc stayed put and I was able to amend the background colour etc.

Comment: A bit more work needs to be done for the hover over as it defaults back to the initial style but can probably over write this with another class:hover

Comment: If possible, it's better to use CSS. Javascript takes time execute, so you will see old styling until your Javascript kicks in. It won't look very pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to have some additional/different for particular buttons, simply give the buttons some classes like class="mybuttonclass otherbuttonclass" - multiple classes are allowed.  Then, just add css rules for your class(es)

```
.mybuttonclass
{
   background-color: red;
}
.otherbuttonclass
{
   color:white;
}
```

thus the background is red with white text - or whatever combination you wish, which would override items in the cascade (CSS) above it. (assumption is that your .CSS file is linked in AFTER the jquery UI css file, or is in-line on the page, both of which would override the jQuery UI css.

Comment: You need to also consider the specificity of the selectors.  I haven't looked in depth at the latest UI CSS, but my experience with 1.7 is that you need to replicate the UI selector structure used in order to guarantee that your overrides will apply in all circumstances.

Comment: @ tvanfosson, good point, making the perhaps erronious assumption that the css selector such as button.mybuttonclass is universal knowlege on my part is not so wonderful :).